# How to show an uploaded image by user from one component to another component?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I am working on an Angular app with routing, where I have three components: app-createimage, app-page-builder, and app-page-editor. The flow is as follows: the user uploads an image using the app-image-upload-button component inside app-createimage. After uploading, I want to navigate to the /editimage route and show the image in that component.

createimage-component.html

```
<app-image-upload-button (uploadComplete)="handleUploadComplete($event)">
</app-image-upload-button>
```

createimage-component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-createimage',
  templateUrl: './createimage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./createimage.component.scss']
})
export class CreateimageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { };

  uploadedImage: string | undefined;

  handleUploadComplete(uploadedImageUrl: string): void {
    this.uploadedImage = uploadedImageUrl;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

image-upload-button.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="showButton === true">
  <div id="main-app" class="container">
    <div id="main-intro">
      <h1 id="main-title">UPLOAD AN IMAGE</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="upload-container">
      <span class="material-icons">file_upload</span>
      <input
        type="file"
        style="display: none"
        #fileInput
        (change)="handleFileUpload($event)"
      />
      <button class="upload-button" (click)="openImageUploader()">
        Create Image
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

image-upload-button.component.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  Output,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef,
  OnInit,
} from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import * as uuid from 'uuid';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-upload-button',
  templateUrl: './image-upload-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image-upload-button.component.scss'],
})
export class ImageUploadButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput!: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
  @Output() uploadComplete = new EventEmitter<string>();
  showButton: boolean = true;
  imageId: string = '';

  constructor(private data: DataService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.data.addData);
  }

  openImageUploader(): void {
    this.fileInput.nativeElement.value = '';
    this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();
  }

  generateImageId(): string {
    const timestamp = moment().valueOf().toString(); // Get the current timestamp
    const uniqueId = uuid.v4().replace(/-/g, ''); // Generate a unique identifier
    this.imageId = timestamp + '_' + uniqueId; // Combine the timestamp and unique identifier
    return this.imageId;
  }

  handleFileUpload(event: Event): void {
    const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    if (input.files && input.files.length > 0) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e: any) => {
        const uploadedImageUrl = e.target.result;
        console.log('uploadedImageUrl', uploadedImageUrl);
        this.uploadComplete.emit(uploadedImageUrl);
        this.showButton = false;
        this.generateImageId();
        this.router.navigate(['/editimage'], {
          queryParams: { image_id: this.imageId },
        });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }
}
```

page-builder.component.html

```
<app-page-editor></app-page-editor>
```

app-routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { PageBuilderComponent } from './page-builder/page-builder.component';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout/layout.component';
import { CreateimageComponent } from './createimage/createimage.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: LayoutComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'editimage',
    component: PageBuilderComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'createimage',
    component: CreateimageComponent,
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

page-builder.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-builder',
  templateUrl: './page-builder.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page-builder.component.scss']
})
export class PageBuilderComponent {
  @Input() uploadedImage: string | undefined;
}
```

page-editor.component.html

```
`<div class="page-builder" *ngIf="uploadedImage">
  <div class="image-edit">
    <img
      width="750"
      height="300"
      class="interactive-image interactive-Image e6b9iw12"
      [src]="uploadedImage"
      alt="Uploaded Image"
    />
  </div>
</div>`
```

page-editor.component.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-editor',
  templateUrl: './page-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page-editor.component.scss'],
})
export class PageEditorComponent {
  @Input() uploadedImage: string | undefined;

  constructor(){}
}
```

Problem: When the user clicks upload image it shows the empty components in the DOM like this below.

`<app-page-builder _nghost-clb-c33=""><app-page-editor _ngcontent-clb-c33="" _nghost-clb-c32=""><!--bindings={}--></app-page-editor></app-page-builder>`

Why?

**NOTE: The image is uploaded successfully, I can see the image in console log**

Answer (score 0):

`app-page-editor` takes the input `uploadedImage`, so you have to use it like this in the template of page-builder.component:

```
<app-page-editor [uploadedImage]="uploadedImage"></app-page-editor>
```

Comment: Hi Andre I tried that but still the  shows empyt component, <app-page-builder _nghost-gct-c33=""><app-page-editor _ngcontent-gct-c33="" _nghost-gct-c32=""><!--bindings={}--></app-page-editor></app-page-builder>

Comment: You emit the image url, but I see no code, where this emitted event is catched. We also don't know, wheter we talk here about parent-child or sibling components. You could pass the image url f. e. with a service and `BehaviorSubject` or with route state to the desired component. There are some possibilities.

Comment: @derstauner The flow is as follows: the user uploads an image using the app-image-upload-button component inside app-createimage. After uploading, I want to navigate to the /editimage route and show the image in that component.  event is cached in page builder , I have provided everything I have

Comment: @derstauner I used service as you suggested and solved my problem thanks

Comment: Then fell free to accept the answer.